# Как добавить новую стадию в режим Сроки (Задачи и проекты) Битрикс24?

Tags: windows, 1с, интерфейс, битрикс24, crm

Как добавить новую стадию в режим Сроки (Задачи и проекты) Битрикс24? Прошу **не минусовать**, я **новичок** в настройке Битрикс24.

**P.S.** На [Как настроить стадии](https://helpdesk.bitrix24.ru/open/10133994/) сказано

> Чтобы добавить новую стадию - нажмите на плюс и задайте название.

В режиме Сроки (Задачи и проекты) нет кнопки + для добавления стадий (можете убедиться сами). (есть кнопка + для добавления быстрой задачи, но не для стадии).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Критерием для оценки вопроса, есть его качество и соответствие правилам платформы, а не то, новичек Вы или нет. [Как настроить стадии](https://helpdesk.bitrix24.ru/open/10133994/)

Comment: `Чтобы создать стадию, наведите мышку на любую из стадий и нажмите на плюсик.`, [Канбан в CRM](https://helpdesk.bitrix24.ru/open/4773569). Если же у Вас такого функционала нет, обращайтесь в поддержку.